# add hyperlinks to table entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, highcharts

I have an html table and I want to hyperlink the entries in one column.

fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/uF4H7/5/ - note once you click on any bar in the graph, there will be an onclick event to show the table.

On the table I want to be able link from clicking on any adId. ie once an adId is clicked it should go to 'www.url.com/adId#. Can this be done in html/js? I've tried creating the link and appending it but haven't had much success. Do I need to refactor how I append entries to the table? Or is it possible rather to create an on-click event on the table?

here is the code on how the table is generated:

```
function appendAds(date1) {
    nonUTCdate = new Date(date1);
    UTCdate = new Date(nonUTCdate.getUTCFullYear(), nonUTCdate.getUTCMonth(), nonUTCdate.getUTCDate());
    $('#tableTitle').html("<u>Info for " + timeConverter(UTCdate) + ":</u>");
    $("#table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#table tr").show();
    for (var i = 0; i < preGroupData.length; i++) {
        if ((date1 >= preGroupData[i].startDate) && (date1 <= preGroupData[i].endDate)) {;
        $('#table').append('<tr><td align="center">' + timeConverter(preGroupData[i].startDate) + '</td><td align="center">' + timeConverter(preGroupData[i].endDate) + '</td><td align="center">' + preGroupData[i].adId + '</td><td align="center">' + preGroupData[i].impressions + '</td></tr>');
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can simply turn the column with preGroupData[i].adId into a link to 'www.url.com/#adId' by adding the anchor text to the html string you are inserting into the html.

replace

```
<td align="center">' + preGroupData[i].adId + '</td>
```

in your string with:

```
<td align="center><a href='www.url.com/#" + preGroupData[i].adId +"'>" 
              + preGroupData[i].adId + "</a></td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

the click handler:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(3)').click(function(){ 
   window.location.href = $(this).text()    
}
```

As an HTTP redirect (back button will not work )

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

like if you click on a link (it will be saved in the session history, so back button will work as expected)

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save the cell to a variable, you can easily add an "on click" event, like this:

```
function appendAds(date1) {
    nonUTCdate = new Date(date1);
    UTCdate = new Date(nonUTCdate.getUTCFullYear(), nonUTCdate.getUTCMonth(),     nonUTCdate.getUTCDate());
    $('#tableTitle').html("<u>Info for " + timeConverter(UTCdate) + ":</u>");
    $("#table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#table tr").show();
    for (var i = 0; i < preGroupData.length; i++) {
        if ((date1 >= preGroupData[i].startDate) && (date1 <= preGroupData[i].endDate)) {;
        var row = $("<tr />")
            .append("<td align='center'>" + timeConverter(preGroupData[i].startDate) + "</td>")
            .append("<td align='center'>" + timeConverter(preGroupData[i].endDate) + "</td>");
        var adIdCell = $("<td align='center'>" + preGroupData[i].adId + "</td>").appendTo(row);

        row.append("<td align='center'>" + preGroupData[i].impressions + "</td>");

            row.appendTo("#table");
            adIdCell.on("click", function() {
                location.href = "./#" + preGroupData[i].adId;
            });
       }
   }
}
```